# How to handle null tables in linq left join

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm writing linq query as below: -

```
from eventDetails in CurrentDataContext.EventCarriers
join eventlog in CurrentDataContext.EventLogCarriers on eventDetails.EventID equals eventlog.EventId into hhh
from eventlog in hhh.DefaultIfEmpty()
join quiz in CurrentDataContext.QuizCarriers on eventDetails.EventID equals competition.EventId into aaa
from quiz in aaa.DefaultIfEmpty()

where eventDetails.EventID == eventId && eventDetails.EventStatusId == 1 && eventlog.CreatedBy == userId                                      
group new { eventDetails, quiz, eventlog } by new
{
  eventDetails.EventID,
  eventDetails.Name                                        
} into g
select new VenueModel
{
  Name = g.Key.Name,
  EventId = g.Key.EventID,
  StartDate = g.Key.StartDate,
  EndDate = g.Key.EndDate,
  EventDescr = g.Key.EventDescr,
  EventIconPath = g.Key.EventIconPath,
  EventImagePath = g.Key.EventImagePath,
  Prizes = (from a in g.Select(a => a.competitions)
                  group a by new
                  {
                      a.PrizeId,
                      a.PrizeIconPath,
                      a.CompetitionDescr,
                      a.PrizeImagePath,
                      a.EndDate,
                      a.StartDate,
                      a.Name,
                      a.EventId,
                      a.StatusId
                  } into x

                  select new CCompetitionModel
                  {
                      PrizeDescrption = x.Key.PrizeDescr,
                      PrizeIconPath = x.Key.PrizeIconPath,
                      PrizeId = x.Key.PrizeId,                                                              
                  }).ToList(),
}).FirstOrDefault();
```

But I'm getting an error like **The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.**

Answer (score 0):

```
//Declare your class property nullable.
//For example, if you are getting start date null from database, then your property will be like following.


    public class Event
    {
      public DateTime? StartDate{get; set;}
      //add other properties of this class here..
    }
```